# Layout with Textview and Spinner and diagonal slash

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to place a Textview and a Spinner in the same layout with a half background with a slash as shown in image

Comment: If you are specifically talking about that slash I would have created a kind of bg image in photoshop and set it as bg ..

Comment: In the future, you should try to make your title sum up the problem in a way that is independent of images in the post to help people differentiate it from many other posts asking for layout help - it'll also help you get more attention to your post.  I've gone ahead and improved it a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Text with image = `TextView` and `TextView.setcompounddrawableswithintrinsicbounds()`

slash = background for `TextView` in xml `android:background="@drawable/srcDrawable"` for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/primaryGreen"
        android:pathData="M0,0
        6,24
        24,24
        24,0
        z"
        android:strokeColor="@color/primaryGreen" />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `layout` normally with one `Spinner` and One `TextView`. You can set the background fo parent layout as `android:background="@drawable/customBg`

Create the below background as below.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:pathData="M0,0
         0,24
         13,24
         11,0
         z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:pathData="M11,0
         13,24
         24,24
         24,0
         z" />
</vector>
```